# Information Extraction from a document, with not much training set

Tags: regex, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-parsing

- **What I want to do:**
  Extract basic biographic information from a text document. (Relation Extraction to be specific)
- **Explanation:**
  I have n text documents containing biographies of n different people. I want to extract information corresponding to their names, age, qualifications, affiliations and interests.
- **What I was able to do:**
  I used Stanford NER to extract name, age and organization in some cases. However, there were many False Positives as well as False Negatives-specially for "organization" tag.
- **Why is it difficult:**
  As it is a biographic document, it contains text associated with the concerned person. I can't use the other documents for training my classifier as things will be totally different for another person.
  Yes, I surely can write some rules. However, that is restricting my domain considerably. For example, I wrote rules to extract qualification..simple ones being: if any of the degrees (in my pre-specified dictionary) is present in a sentence, I can extract entities from that sentence and try to find a relation.
- **My question:**
  Is there any way of making this task automatic? Since we are analyzing just one document each time, please don't suggest me to use bootstrapping based approaches. I tried learning patterns from collecting specific sentences from each document and then applying bootstrap-based algorithms like Snowball, but failed miserably.
  I am aware that parsing might help me over here, I am trying to learn some patterns from the dependency parse of specific sentences..however I am not really sure how to proceed with it.
  I thought of applying distant supervision learning, however that too requires a large dataset.
- **Personal Take (till now):**
  Such problem could be solved by rule-based approaches augmented by parsing-based methods. However, I am not yet able to incorporate probabilistic or statistical model to generalize it for different types of biographies.

PS: I want to change the latter sentence of my "Personal Take". Hence, seeking help.

An example:
Document containing following text:
Tim obtained his PhD from Stanford University in 2010. He did his bachelor (hons) from Massachusetts Institute of Technology in 2004. Currently, he is working in ABC company.

Should extract facts in the form: [Entity1, Relation, Entity2]
Ex: [Tim, affiliation-PhD, Stanford University],
[He(Resolved to Tim), affiliation-bachelor(hons), Massachusetts Institute of Technology] and
[He(Resolved t Tim), affiliation-works, ABC]

Answer (score 1):

An example would help.  For instance, if the biography is structured then you can use AWK or GREP in a bash script.  If you haven't already considered that option, post an example for us to chew on.

Another option is to use Amazon Turk or another human microtask tool.  For relatively little money you can have humans extract the information for you.  Some tools such as CrowdFlower provide statistical analysis of the results that takes into account the past performance of the workers.  You can use redundancy and voting to further refine your results.  I've used CrowdFlower in the past and have gotten very goo results.  They've changed their business model to focuses on large accounts so this may no longer be an option.  I would start with the Turk.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I have posted an example. Is that what you were looking for? The document is mostly semi-structured or unstructured.

Comment: I am planning to use the Turk, but haven't yet figured out whether I should go for tagging first, and then finding relations or should I adopt any other strategy. 
The dataset I am using requires tagging, and as you can see it is not a conventional tagging problem which Stanford NER can resolve. In such case, I have to go for manual tagging..
I can either tag myself or go for the Turk. However, I am not sure of the authenticity in the latter case. Any thoughts?

Comment: OK, REGEX is not appropriate.

Comment: I've used CrowdFlower a couple of times and it's very authentic.  They use workers from a variety of networks including Mechanical Turk.  You can use a few different controls.  The most important is control questions.  You, as the researcher, complete a control set of tasks and annotate your answers.  You then have workers complete blocks of, say, 8 tasks.  In the 8, 2 are your controls and 6 are new.  You use the 2 to validate the worker and to provide feedback tot he worker.  If one or 2 of the controls are answered incorrectly you throw out the answers to the 6 new tasks.

Comment: The worker gets to see your annotation on the control questions that they answer incorrectly to get abetter sense of how you want the task completed.  If a worker has a correct response rate below a prescribed threshold, then they are removed from the pool of workers and all of their results are removed from the data.  When I used them, CrowdFlower didn't charge for work that was thrown out.  CrowdFlower also uses lifetime statistics of the workers on your project to further provide a confidence rating for the data.

Comment: And finally I had 3 workers do each task and used voting to determine confidence in the data.  By combining control questions, voting and lifetime worker statistics, CrowdFlower is able to assign a confidence to each task result that produces extremely good data.

Comment: There are other services and you can use Mechanical Turk directly.  At the time I chose CrowdFlower I felt that Turk was "some assembly required".  while I could have done the work, the low additional cost of CrowdFlower was worth allowing me to focus on the data collection.  You may make a different choice.  Look at the options and consider your problem and talk to others who have used other approaches.  But human microtasking is an amazing tool for collecting hig-quality data.  Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this offering from Stanford:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml

Comment: Thanks! That's a new tool in the bucket.
How successful is open IE in scaling across documents of different genres?